# Microsoft Excel - Unique Time stamp entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to insert a time stamp into column "D" when column "A" has data inputed. However, I'd like these time stamps to be unique. Everytime I insert any new data into a cell in column D, all the timestamps in column a change
The formula I currently have is:
=IF(AND(A6<>"",ISTEXT(A6)),NOW(),"")
=IF(AND(A7<>"",ISTEXT(A7)),NOW(),"")
etc

Comment: Because NOW() is a volatile function, it recalculates everytime the worksheet changes.  So even though you are 15 rows over from where your pertinent data is and you delete a cell, or enter a cell, NOW gets recalculated to the new time.  A static time that is automatically entered as you describe, can only be achieved through VBA if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue can be solved by entering Static Date in Column D.**

**How it works:**

- Select required Cells in `Column D`, **Right 
  Click** and from `Poped up Menu` hit **Format 
  cell**.
- Apply either of **Date Time Format** `mm/dd/yy 
  h:mm AM/PM` or `dd/mm/yy h:mm AM/PM`.
- From **File menu** click **Options**, and from 
  **Formula Tab**, find and check **Enable 
  Iterative Calcilation**, finish with **Ok**, 
  (*Check the Screen Shot below*).

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `D1` & fill down 
  till needed.

  `=IF(A1<>"",IF(D1="",NOW(),D1),"")`
- Now start entering Data in `Column A`, you get 
  `Static Time Stamp in Column D`.

[image]

*Adjust cell reference in the Formula as needed.*